# django calendar widget

Tags: django, calendar, widget

I want to have a calendar in my application, so that every user can pick a date, and submit a meeting poll. I tried using the Django calendar admin widget, but it doesn't appear on my page.
How can i get a calendar for my app? it is easier to use a java script one?

Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with blog posts or Twitter?

Comment: sorry, i've edited,i wanted to ask something about twitter, and forgot to change the name. thanks for understanding!:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try jquery-ui date picker : http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/
It's very easy to integrate it in your form template.

Comment: wow, looks fantastic! i'll try it, and post the result! :) thx!